# How to Create a Spilling Array that Takes a Rolling Average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

Reversing the order of the dates works, but I'm more interested in knowing how to do it in this specific way. I'm trying to take a rolling average, ideally it would be nice to change the depth from a cell using offset. So instead of saying 20, it would say T1 or SMALength.

I'm testing it on the Close from `=STOCKHISTORY("AAPL",6/18/1981,7/13/2022,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5)` loaded in on A1, Sheet1

The current formula is:

```
=IF(ROW(OFFSET($B$2,,,COUNTA(B:B)))-1>20,AGGREGATE(1,6,OFFSET(B2,,,-20)),NA())


IF ( X , Y, NA())
```

X checks to see if the row of numbers is 20 deep while creating a spilled array.

Y is supposed to take an average of the current row with a height of -20, and works when dragged, but not as part of a dynamic spilled array.

---

One deeply inelegant way to do it is to create 20 arrays using

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDEX($A$1#,,2),,)+OFFSET(INDEX($A$1#,,2),1,)+OFFSET(INDEX($A$1#,,2),2,)+OFFSET(INDEX($A$1#,,2),3,)+etc....+OFFSET(INDEX($A$1#,,2),20,))
```

but that wouldn't allow me to dynamically change the length of the SMA.

---

This one is partway there, but the Value if True doesn't update, returning only B11:B31

```
=IF(ROW(OFFSET($B$2,,,COUNT($B$11:$B$100000)))>20,AVERAGE($B11:$B31),NA())
```

Comment: What do you mean by spilling array? To me it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Do you want in each cell the average of the past 20 days or do you want the values from the past 20 days?

Comment: A spilled array is an a formula that you enter into one cell, that "spills" its multiple answer into multiple columns.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531

an example would be =OFFSET($A$1,,,count(A:A))

SInce the time series data is dynamic, the goal is to create a dynamic spilled array (so that I don't have to drag down and have a bunch of pointless formulas for companies with a shorter history) so that I can gather a simple moving average.

Comment: The simple moving average is supposed to be the average of last twenty days for each data point, after the first 20, which I'll leave NA().

Comment: Se essentially if there were 250 days, i would want to create a dynamic spilled array that took the close of days 230-250 and took an average, then I would move down one cell and put the average of days 229-249, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data you provided, the information is stored in the range `A1:F10356`.
What you want to achieve is a row-by-row computation of the moving average for, e.g., the last 20 days. One way to achieve this would be to use the `BYROW()` function:

```
=BYROW(array, [function])
```

The function itself is pretty much self-explanatory. Specify, the array you want to apply the function to, with the function specified in the lambda statement; in your case, the average of the last 20 days.

Since the first 20 rows should be empty, I added a `COUNTIF` statement to account for the fact that you do not want an average if the data contains text, which in one case (row 20) would result in an average of only 19 days, and secondly, you want an empty cell if there is a `#REF!` error, which happens in the first 19 rows because of the -20 `OFFSET`. Use the following formula in cell `G2`:

```
=BYROW(B2:B10356,
LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(row,,,-20),"*")>0,"",AVERAGE(OFFSET(row,,,-20))),"")))
```

However, the biggest downside of this specification is that as soon as your data changes, you also have to adjust the array, i.e., `B2:B10356`, accordingly.

An even more dynamic specification could be achieved by the additional inclusion of the `INDEX` function, which returns the relevant range with values from row 2 to the last row with data:

```
=BYROW(INDEX($B:$B,2,0):INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B),0),
LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(row,,,-20),"*")>0,"",AVERAGE(OFFSET(row,,,-20))),"")))
```

Comment: Just reading through this, it looks like it will work really well. Thank you!

Hurt my back and haven't had a chance to dig in and test yet, but I read through the functions on Microsoft's website, and they look like exactly what I need.

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this out today and it worked perfectly! It's a nifty solution that I've been able to use to solve a bunch of other problems I'd been having as well, so thanks a ton.